# SQL Query for deleting all from table keeping only required row

Tags: mysql, sql

I've below `test` table in MySQL.

```
fid sid data
A   B   67
C   D   54
E   F   53
G   H   26
I   J   23
K   L   17
M   N   64
O   P   83
Q   R   93
S   T   45
U   V   98
W   X   28
Y   Z   51
```

This table will get more data everyday. Now my objective is to keep only few rows here and delete everything else from here. Now what rows to keep, that has to be fetched from another table.
Let's take an example, that we need to keep only rows where (fid = I and sid = J) and (fid = S and sid = T) and (fid = C and sid = D). Now I need query which keeps only these rows deleting everything else from here.

I tried the below query but it doesn't seem to work.

```
DELETE FROM `test` WHERE (`fid` != 'I' AND `sid` != 'J') AND (`fid` != 'S' AND `sid` != 'T') AND (`fid` != 'C' AND `sid` != 'D')
```

Please help me on same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the condition like this:

```
DELETE FROM `test` 
WHERE (fid, sid) NOT IN (('I', 'J'), ('S', 'T'), ('C', 'D'))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fVepWArbWGRii32QUGhnsB/0).
Results:

```
| fid | sid | data |
| --- | --- | ---- |
| C   | D   | 54   |
| I   | J   | 23   |
| S   | T   | 45   |
```

If the rows that you want to keep are fetched by a query then change to this:

```
DELETE FROM `test` 
WHERE (fid, sid) NOT IN (SELECT col1, col2 FROM .....)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got an answer for this question.

```
DELETE FROM `test` WHERE NOT (fid = 'I' AND sid = 'J') AND NOT (fid = 'S' AND sid = 'T') AND NOT (fid = 'C' AND sid = 'D')
```